# How to export Slack conversation thread without admin account

Tags: slack, accessibility

The Slack UI is not ideal for some conversations/threads I participate in, where it would be better to have the text and images copied to another format that I can more easily read and process.

I am not an administrator for the Slack forum in question, so I can't do the bulk export that it looks like admins can do.

Are there other (command-line or GUI) tools I can use with my (non-admin) Slack credentials, to access the text and image content of conversations I have with other Slack users, so that the conversation is more accessible?

Comment: Alex, did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 15):

You can also use [this project](https://github.com/rusq/slackdump) to export your slack conversations without having an admin account or having to add a Slack application.

The latest version can understand slack URL links (i.e. Copy Link in Slack), has a simple text UI and can generate a Mattermost compatible export file.

Comment: Tried the project: channels are exported fine, but DM are not. Probably the reason is that I do not get any DM when running `slackdump -c` as shown in the example, I get just channels. Running `slackdump <U01xxxxxxxx>` is also of no help, the app reports `channel_not_found`.

Comment: This worked for me for both DMs and a (private) channel just now. I'm currently on a free trial of the Slack Pro plan.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a command line tool called [slackchannel2pdf](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackchannel2pdf/releases) that can export any Slack channel to a PDF file (text only).

You do not need an admin account, but you need a Slack token with some permissions (from your admins) to use it.

The main release is for Windows, but it's made in Python so it can run on most platforms.

Full disclosure: I am the author of this tool. Its open source and you can use it free of charge.

Answer (score 5):

- Go to slack.com/customize - log in to your workspace
- In the browser console, run `TS.boot_data.api_token` to get your xoxs token (source: https://github.com/jackellenberger/emojme)
- Clone this project or any derivative https://github.com/chr1spy1/slack-export (check the doc for export options)
- Run: `python slack_export.py --token "xoxs-...."`

If you need html exports for readability, there are some projects out there to convert exported Slack json files into html

Comment: Can this be done if you are not an administrator for the Slack channel?

Comment: Yes, this works also if you aren't a Slack admin.

Answer (score 5):

You can check [Backupery for Slack](https://www.backupery.com/products/backupery-for-slack/) tool that allows you to export any channel (and the related threads) from Slack and convert it to HTML. It will also download all the files from a selected conversation and put the links into the HTML.

<s>Please also note, that depending on your workspace settings you may or may not be allowed to install the applications on Slack. If you are not allowed to install the apps, you may refer to [this article](https://www.backupery.com/can-i-use-backupery-for-slack-without-owner-or-admin-permissions/).</s> Starting from v. 2082 it is possible to use the *desktop* version of the app without installation into a workspace.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the developer of the app and the app is not free, but a free trial is available.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Thanks for being aware of the self-promotion rules, appreciated!

Comment: Can this be done if you are not an administrator for the Slack channel, i.e. without having an administrator intervene?

Comment: @AlexReynolds It depends on the workspace settings. If the workspace settings allow users to install applications on Slack without being Administrators, then yes, this can be done. By default, only Primary Owner, Owners, Admins and Full Members are allowed to install any applications for Slack. However, a workspace Admin or Owner may limit installations to pre-approved apps. If the app is not on the list, then the installation will fail. You can read more [here](https://www.backupery.com/can-i-use-backupery-for-slack-without-owner-or-admin-permissions/) about the details.

Comment: Okay, thanks; it isn't possible, then.

Comment: Starting from v. 2082 it is possible to use the app without installation into your workspace.

Answer (score -1):

For those who only need to print a conversation with a user or from a simple channel, there is a simple solution under Winodws only: select the whole conversation from within the text itself (Control-A will select the current page and all history above), copy it to One Note (just C-C -> one note tab, C-V).
It keeps the layout BUT does NOT include the attachments.
It's "quick and dirty" but sufficient for simple conversation and threads.
It keeps the users pictures and date and time of messages, though.
The one note page includes the link to the actual slack page (https://app.slack.com/client///...)